# Is it safe to wrap std::async in object

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, future

I wrapped [std::async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) in a class similar to this:

```
class AsyncTask
{
public:
    AsyncTask() {}
    ~AsyncTask()
    {
        m_shouldTerminate.store(true, std::memory_order::memory_order_release);
    }

    std::future<int> runAsync()
    {
        return std::async(std::launch::async, [this]() { threadMain(); return m_result; });
    }

private:
    void threadMain()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<std::numeric_limits<int>::max(); ++i)
        {
            if (m_shouldTerminate.load(std::memory_order::memory_order_acquire))
            {
                break;
            }

            // do time consuming calculation but abort if m_shouldTerminate becomes true
            m_result += foo([this]() { return m_shouldTerminate.load(std::memory_order::memory_order_acquire); });
        }
    }

    int m_result = 0;
    std::atomic<bool> m_shouldTerminate = false;
};
```

AFAIK [std::future::~future](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/%7Efuture) blocks if the future was returned from [std::async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async). This would mean that for code like

```
{
    AsyncTask myTask;
    myTask.runAsync();
}

bar();
```

It would block in the temporary future's destructor, then destruct `myTask` and only then the call to `bar()` would happen. Considering this it should be ensured that the lifetime of any `AsyncTask` object exceeds the run time of the task itself and my implementation should be safe.

If AsyncTask is dynamically allocated this guarantee would no longer hold, obviously.

Are my assumptions correct an is my implementation safe? In particular is it possible that an AsyncTask object is destroyed while the async task is still running?

Comment: I don't think you want `std::memory_order::memory_order_acquire` here. And maybe this belongs on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: moreover, even with a task of automatic storage duration, the future may be moved somehere else ( or moved into a shared_future and copied anywhere ). So, no, blocking on future dtor does not gives much guarantees on this regard; afaik, the reason why it's there is to provide a zombie-thread scope guard for the returned future, that's it